# How to install specific docker version from apt-cache policy docker-ce candidate list

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, docker, apt-cache

**Command "Docker-ce" list all candidates**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/master# apt-cache policy docker-ce
docker-ce:  
   Installed: (none)   
   Candidate: 5:19.03.6~3-0~ubuntu-xenial
   Version table:
     5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
      500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

**Then when issue the command using the string value from the candidate list fails**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/master# sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu-xenial docker-ce-cli=18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu-xenial containerd.io 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu-xenial' for 'docker-ce' was not found 
E: Version '18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu-xenial' for 'docker-ce-cli' was not found
```

How can i do to install an specific version from the list(the list is not complete because Ask Ubuntu don't allow me to paste more than 8 links)

I require this because the newest version 19.xx.xx is not compatible/supported by Kubernetes and cluster build fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here the answer to how to install the desired docker version:**

- Update the apt package index

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- To install a specific version of Docker Engine - Community, list the available versions in the repo, then select and install

  ```
  apt-cache madison docker-ce
  ```

- Then finally select the version to install from the listed ones

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
  ```

This will help a lot to people getting into the docker world, Enjoy!

Comment: It's your own question, but aren't you just repeating what you did there?

Comment: don't forget to run the same command for `docker-ce-cli` . also possible like in my case you will have to additionally downgrade your version of docker compose as it remained an updated version even after rolling back docker itself.

Answer (score 4):

You double-clicked the version in `apt-cache`'s output, expecting to select it whole. But at least `gnome-terminal` treats colon as a separator for selection!
So you lost the leading `5:` from the version.

Got stumped at the same problem just now, and it surprised the heck out of me! I guess colons in package versions are quite rare.